# Issue about Characthers

Tags: fonts, lxc

i use in LXC, Ubuntu 21.04 (GNU/Linux 5.11.22-5-pve x86_64) on Proxmox.

I have an issue, because i see weird, some filename.

For example:
You're next (2011).mp4

But i can see in the shell:

```
You'\''re next (2011).mp4
```

How can i fix it ?

```
root@PLEX:/mnt/ROB_MASTER/Movies# **locale**
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I use these files in plex, so are important that name match, or scraper, can't handle posters, plot etc...

Comment: In what shell? In the terminal?

Comment: yes in the terminal, and plex can't handle the right name, so scraper to get from web, info about movies, isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error! it is called Quoting, basically, the quotation mark in 'You're next (2011).mp4' would be considered as a start of a string literal if it wasn't preceded by a backslash:

**From `man bash`**:

```
QUOTING
       Quoting  is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to
       the shell.  Quoting can be used to disable special treatment for special charac‐
       ters,  to  prevent  reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent
       parameter expansion.
```

also [look here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell)